# Meteor templates security

Tags: security, templates, meteor

I am relatively new to Meteor and wanted to check if Meteor templates are exposed to the client? For example, if I look up and set sensitive information as a variable in a meteor template, would a savvy user be able to find and view that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the templates are pretty much client side only.  Dropping into the console in your browser you can query collections, look at template data, and call any of Meteors client side functionality, including making calls back to the server.